# White navigation bar Vs black

Tags: navigation-bar

On an amoled display, in theory, shouldn't the navbar be black to reduce burn in?

Then why are apps/phones starting to use white nav bars?

Comment: "Questions which are Android-independent are off-topic. Consider taking advantage of other resources that may be appropriate for your question." - this question is about displays in general, not about Android OS.

Comment: As for the question itself though, I think you're missing the big picture. It's true that on AMOLED screens, black burns the slowest, and white the fastest. However, even before the introduction of Material Design, most apps have bright-colored (white) interfaces. That combined with a black navbar will produce uneven burn-in speed on the two parts, forming a gradually visible line between them, and that's how you notice the burn-in problem. In essence, white navbars are an effort to even out the burn-in rate of the whole display.

Comment: Also white navigation bars creates an illusion of increased viewing area.